# Change xfce4 keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce4

I have a simple question. I know how to edit `xfce4` keyboard shortcuts (Settings->Keyboard). But I am used to open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>(the one we comment here with, above the TAB). I've set it up, I can see it in `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts`, but it simply doesn't work. I mean, if I set it f.e to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then it works, but when I press my combination, it displays this message:

[image: screenshot]

Now, this is probably a shortcut in some network manager. How can I switch it off, to make my one work?